# Python regex with string tokenization

Tags: python, regex

In Python 2.7, I've got the following string:

```
"$a first answer$b second answer$c third answer$d fourth answer$SOLUTION: a"
```

How can I properly parse it using a regex and store it in an array as shown below?

```
['first answer', 'second answer', 'third answer', 'fourth answer', 'a']
```

From what I've read so far I believe I have to somehow compile my regex and run it against that string using the `match` method, but I'm not quite certain of how to do this.

Comment: Have you written a regex? Have you tried to `re.compile` it? Have you read e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x="$a first answer$b second answer$c third answer$d fourth answer$SOLUTION: a"
print [i for i in re.split(r"\$\S+",x) if i]
```

You can do it simply by `split`.

Comment: Clean and simple. Will do the job just as fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a bit more complicated regex that is more tailored to your specific case:

```
s = "$a first answer$b second answer$c third answer$d fourth answer$SOLUTION: a"
print(filter(None, re.split(r"\$(?:[a-z]\b|SOLUTION:)\s*", s)))
```

This  will reduce the risk of overmatching and will trim the resulting list items.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/rtKMNm)

In case you really can have any word after `$` optionally followed with `:`, you can use

```
print(filter(None, re.split(r"(?i)\$[a-z]+\b:?\s*", s)))
```